# How to filter all rows in excel with find function using loop in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on a project to filter all rows in Excel with condition that contains yesterday's date and append filtered rows with column names into a new workbook. I've tried and searched all over the place but failed to accomplish this goal. Here is the input file:

```
Court # Received Date               column b      column c
502419/2020
01/30/2020                            xxx           xxx
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```
import xlrd
sheet_data = []
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('path to input file')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
i = 0 
for i in range (sh.nrows):
    if i != sh.row_values.str.find('02/25/2020'):
        i += 1
    else:
        sheet_data.append(i)
```

Errors that produced is 'function' object has no attribute 'str'. I changed it to contains function which produces the same result.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: What is the purpose of `i`?

Comment: Can you  provide excel file instead of an image?

Comment: @roganjosh I guess what i want to do here is to loop through all rows..

Comment: So why are you defining `i` and then doing `for i in range (sh.nrows):`, and incrementing `i` in the loop? Python doesn't work like, say, Javascript, where you need to initialise some loop variable

Comment: @rolf82 edited.

Comment: @roganjosh let me remove it and run it again

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Why are you using xlrd? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. Ultimately I think this is going to be too broad, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials, or documentation.

Comment: @AMC edited. apologies for formatting. kind of new to ask questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent way too long coming up with a solution. Google's results were pretty poor and all gave the same resultl. What you needed was openpyxl.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# requires openpyxl, xlrd

file = 'FILENAME.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=None)
yest = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
yest = yest.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
df2: pd.DataFrame = df[df['COLUMN A'].str.contains(yest)]

df2.to_excel('filtered.xlsx', index=False)
```

Using just openpyxl you can try this:

```py
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
wb2 = openpyxl.workbook.Workbook(write_only=True)
wb2.create_sheet('sheet1')
sh1 = wb1[wb1.sheetnames[0]]
sh2 = wb2['sheet1']
sh2.append(next(sh1.iter_rows()))
yest = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m/%d/%y')
for row in sh1.iter_rows():
    if yest in row[0].value:
        sh2.append((cell.value for cell in row))

wb2.save("filtered.xlsx")
```

Comment: all codes make sense except this line: df2: pd.DataFrame = df[df['COLUMN A'].str.contains(yest)] could you please clarify it a bit? thank you

Comment: I was able to reproduce your suggested codes but I was getting an error: "unalignable boolean series provided by indexer (index of the boolean series and of the indexed object do not match)". I checked data type of column a and it turns out to be boolean. also, the format in column a is 123456/2020\n02/18/2020. Does str.contains() function has limit on how original column is formatted? thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @liamsuma

Comment: @liamsuma I added another solution, try that one

Comment: Good morning. thanks for your reply. Another error pops up when I walk through your codes - `lxml.etree.lxml syntax error: not in an element`. my guess is that it has something to do with date format from the original workbook as I mentioned above. The workbook 2 saved with no values contained but column names when I remove `yest = ...`. The 1st solution works fine except the date filter.

Comment: Could you send me the first 3 rows of the first column? as an excel file?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you realize but yest will always equal yesteday's date. If you want a differnet date set it manually e.g. `yest = '02/25/2020'

Comment: Yes. For yesterday's date, I will always need yesterday's date to filter out court records so that I don't need to change date every morning when I check results from court.

Comment: I also edited the OP with updated column name and values in that column

Comment: ahhh... it works... spent too much time on this.. thanks eli for your help. The edited solution works perfect.